# IF(CONTAINS) question from an MPL

Tags: formula, multi-select, if, contains

I am trying to aggregate data from an MPL into a separate field with fewer values. When I run the formulas, it is only returning the first value. Is there a way to rewrite the formula so that all true values are returned?

```
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"White or Anglo"),"White or Anglo",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"White or Anglo (e.g. White English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British / American / etc.)"),"White or Anglo",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Black"),"Black",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Negra"),"Black",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Black / African / Caribbean / Black British"),"Black",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Asian"),"Asian",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Asiática"),"Asian",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Arab"),"Middle Eastern, North African or Arab",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Middle Eastern, North African or Arab"),"Middle Eastern, North African or Arab",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Middle Eastern"),"Middle Eastern, North African or Arab",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"North African or Arab"),"Middle Eastern, North African or Arab",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Árabe, Norte-Africano ou de origem no Oriente Médio"),"Middle Eastern, North African or Arab",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Árabe"),"Arab",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Latinx or Hispanic"),"Latin",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Latina or Hispânica"),"Latin",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Indigenous"),"Indigenous or Native",
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Indígena"),"Indigenous or Native","Other")))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation operator `&`

```
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"White or Anglo"),"White or Anglo;",null) &
if(includes(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,"Black"),"Black;",null) & 
...
```

I assumed a delimiter of `;` but you could use anything